# Browser tab/theme color toggle with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

The concept is that, on clicking a button, the colorscheme of the page content toggles to dark mode along with the browser tab color. I came up with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<style>

body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #10101c;
    color: grey;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #10101c;
  color: #778899;
}

.dark-mode .btn {
    background: #10101c;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid #002e43;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
<p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>
<button class="btn" onclick="toggle()">Toggle dark mode</button>

<script>
function toggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    var yo = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

    if yo.hasAttribute("content", "#ffffff");
    {
    yo.setAttribute("content", "#10101c"); 
    }
    else {
    yo.setAttribute("content", "#ffffff");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Where am I going wrong? The main area of concentration is the JS area.
p.s. I'm novice in JS

Comment: What is the error? Is the `meta` attribute read anywhere to actually toggle the light/dark mode? Please clarify your problem so we can help you better. PS: While your approach isn't invalid, you might want to consider toggling a `dark`/`light` class on your `body` instead — way easier to style with CSS that way. :)

Comment: Check your first `if` statement, looking for missing parentheses and unwanted semicolons.

Comment: if I removed the script line starting from 'if' upto 'else', and an extra parenthesis, I end up with a partial result, as in the tab color + page color changes from #ffffff to #10101c on first click, however, on second click, the page color turns #ffffff, but the tab color remains #10101c. Hence I ended up writing the above code..but to no vail...it doesn't even toggle the page content colors.

Comment: The meta "theme-color" change the browser tab color. I thought it would be reasonable to change the theme-color along with the page colorscheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but this could be done in a much simpler way. You can just add a click event to the button which runs your `toggle()` function and adds/removes the class from `body` element.

EDIT:
I've updated my answer based on your comment. Rather than using `hasAttribute` in your condition, I think you need `getAttribute`.

```js
var darkButton = document.getElementById("dark-mode");

darkButton.addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle() {
  var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");

  bodyElement.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  var meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

  if (meta.getAttribute("content") === "#ffffff") {
    console.log(meta.getAttribute("content"));
    meta.setAttribute("content", "#10101c");
  } else {
    console.log(meta.getAttribute("content"));
    meta.setAttribute("content", "#ffffff");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.btn {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #10101c;
  color: grey;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: #10101c;
  color: #778899;
}

.dark-mode .btn {
  background: #10101c;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #002e43;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Toggle Dark/Light Mode</h2>
  <p>Click the button to toggle between dark and light mode for this page.</p>
  <button id="dark-mode" class="btn">Toggle dark mode</button>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're on your phone, you've probably noticed the browser tab/navigation bar changes while visiting some websites like facebook, where it changes to a medium blue color. It's due to the meta tag, theme-color. I'm trying to achieve that with the page theme color toggle, as in the page color-scheme changes, along with the tab color. @jihs answer worked half way through though.

Comment: Any ways to add persistence, as when navigating through pages, the dark mode remains there according to user preference, instead of toggling itself to light mode on every page load. I assume it has something to do with cookies. Should I ask a new question for that?

Comment: @SamiulJoy yes please do

Answer (score 3):

**your problem?**

The if statement has a semicolon after the parenthesis in the `if` statement.

```
function toggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    var yo = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]"); //<-- this semicolon

    if yo.hasAttribute("content", "#ffffff"); //<-- this semicolon 
    {
        yo.setAttribute("content", "#10101c"); //<-- this semicolon
    }
else {
        yo.setAttribute("content", "#ffffff"); //<-- and this semicolon are all your problem
    }
}
```

Note: you must put parenthesis at the beginning and end of the if statement.

example:

```
if (9 < 10) {
    console.log("9 is less than 10")
}
```

the `.hasAttribute` only takes one parameter. Your gave it two: 
`if yo.hasAttribute("content", "#ffffff")`

try this instead-

```
function toggle() {
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    let yo = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

    if (yo.hasAttribute("content")) {
        yo.setAttribute("content", "#10101c");
    }
else {
        yo.setAttribute("content", "#ffffff");
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It works, but not completely/intended. On clicking, turns the page content as well as the tab color to #10101c, as intended, but on the second click it turns the page content to #ffffff which is intended, but the tab color remains #10101c. The goal is to toggle that to #ffffff as well (:

Answer (score -2):

SOLVED YOUR QUESTION: (by indoxploit)

TAG:

```
<button id="change-meta-color">BUTTON</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var change_meta = document.getElementById("change-meta-color");
var meta_color = document.createElement("meta");
    meta_color.setAttribute("name","theme-color");
    meta_color.setAttribute("content","hsl(220,100%,50%)");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(meta_color);
function change_color(){  
  if(meta_color.getAttribute('content') === "hsl(220,100%,50%)"){meta_color.setAttribute('content', "hsl(0,0%,0%)");}
  else{meta_color.setAttribute('content', "hsl(220,100%,50%)");}}
change_meta.addEventListener("click", change_color);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).